# Python Django UnboundLocalError while calling a different function

Tags: python, django, urlconf

Not long ago I started programming Python with Django. Sometimes I get strange errors and have no clue, why. So, let's beginn with one of these errors.

I have a View with two functions. Example:

```
def view_post(request, slug):
    """
    Shows a single post
    """
    posts = Post.objects(slug = slug).limit(1)
    for items in posts:
        post = items

    cssClasses = css_class_converter({ _css_class_editable })

    context = RequestContext(request)
    return render_to_response("single.html", { 'post': post, 'class': cssClasses }, context)

def new_post(request):
    '''
    Opens a blank page for creating a new post
    '''

    post = Post()
    cssClasses = css_class_converter({ _css_class_editable, _css_class_new })
    context = RequestContext(request)
    return render_to_response("single.html", {'post': post, 'new': True }, context)
```

Then calling them with my URLconf. Calling view_post function works as It should, without errors.

```
urlpatterns = patterns('blog.views',
    # Examples:
    url(r'^$', views.index),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[^\.]+)', 'view_post', name='view_blog_post'),
    url(r'^new/$', 'new_post', name='new_blog_post'),

...
```

But calling the new_post function runs in a UnboundLocalError Exception on line 39 **"local variable 'post' referenced before assignment"**. Line 39 is render_to_response of the view function, not the new function.

So, **why the heck is my call of the *new* function throwing an error in my *view* function?** Really, I have no clue. I came over from C# so I'm sure I didn't get some special Python rule which makes me coding things wrong.

***Update: The indentation of the two functions isn't correct because of stackoverflow.com code panel. Don't care about it.***

[image]

Comment: The indentation in your example code is inconsistent - if it's like that in your actual code things won't behave as you expect.

Comment: Yeah thanks, I know that but it's just because of stack overflow :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the indentation

```
def view(request):
    ...
    def new(request):
        ...
```

Is different for python of:

```
def view(request):
    ...

def new(request):
    ...
```

You should be sure use spaces for indentation and python recommends 4 spaces instead of tab

Update:

The problem is in urls:

```
url(r'^$', views.index),
url(r'^(?P<slug>[^\.]+)', 'view_post', name='view_blog_post'),
url(r'^new/$', 'new_post', name='new_blog_post'),
```

Change it to:

```
url(r'^$', views.index),
url(r'^new/$', 'new_post', name='new_blog_post'),
url(r'^(?P<slug>[^\.]+)', 'view_post', name='view_blog_post'),
```

That is because the url /new/ match the regexp

```
r'^(?P<slug>[^\.]+)'
```

Comment: No, that isn't it. Thats just because I copied my code really ugly. It's ok in original. And wouldn't it throw an indention error instead of a reference error?

Comment: Not really, in python you can define funcs in funcs

Comment: Yes, I know that. But as I said, it's correct in my file. I don't have indentation in my editor. It's just because of the code panel here. I'm going to add a screenshot to clarify that.

Comment: I updated my question and added a screenshot. I'm sure it's not an indentation problem. Is it?

Comment: Oh, damn, you're so right with the URLconf. It would never have occurred to me. Thanks dude, that could be the solution for many of my  problems :D

Comment: My pleasure, btw, please use 4 spaces for indentation XD, And i fixed the indentation in the question

Answer (score 1):

The error definitely sounds like the `view_post` view function is being called. Are you sure that your urlpatterns are the right way around? Or both URL regexes could be pointed at `view_post`.

In `view_post` if the query finds no items, then the variable `post` that is only set in the for loop will not have been set, and the reference to it in `render_to_response` will raise the `UnboundLocalError`.

You can avoid that by setting post to None before the loop.

```
def view_post(request, slug):
        """
        Shows a single post
        """
        posts = Post.objects(slug = slug).limit(1)
        post = None   # Ensure post is bound even if there are no posts matching slug
        for items in posts:
            post = items

        cssClasses = css_class_converter({ _css_class_editable })

        context = RequestContext(request)
        return render_to_response("single.html", { 'post': post, 'class': cssClasses }, context)
```

You can see why the UnboundLocalError is happening using this simpler function:

```
def first_element(items):
    for item in items:
        result = item
        break
    return result
```

(Obviously, you wouldn't really implement `first_element` like this, but this illustrates what's happening.)
If you call `first_element` with a non-empty list, it'll work as expected:

```
>>> first_element([2, 3, 4])
2
```

But if you call it with an empty list, result has never been bound, so you'll get the error:

```
>>> first_element([])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in first_element
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'result' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: +1 for the tip. It wasn't the problem but it could also be one in future. Because I use MongoDB instead of the really well supported database mappers I didn't take a look to this details during my first steps. But you're right!